# WordPress: How to realize the relationship between two Custom Taxonomies?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress web site with using WooCommerce.
There are two custom taxonomies (Product Categories and Product Attributes) in WooCommerce.

I need to realize the relationship between Category and Product Attributes for displaying Attributes only related with the chosen Category on the add product page

[image: Add Product Page]

I think I need to display a list of Attributes on the Categories add page.
For example: the Category "Doors" should have only "color", "type of material", "width" and "height" but should't have "depth", "length", "thickness" and so on.

But I don't know how to get a list of Attributes, that related with the chosen Category by user on add product page.

Comment: As per https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unique-attributes-per-category you can't w/o a massive (I guess) customization. What exactly you're trying to achieve? Maybe you've got a XY problem here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm trying to achieve getting a list of attributes wich somehow association with chosen subcategory. When admin adding a new Category, he should see a list of check-boxes with all attributes and choose some of them. When seller adding a new product, he choose a Category and Subcategory (I have a drop-downs of Categories and Subcategories). Then he should to choose an attributes. There is a drop-down with attributes on Woocommerce "Add Product Page". Only attributes wich admin has chosen for Subcategory when he added a Subcategory should be in this Attributes drop-down.

Comment: In WooCommerce attributes can be associated with products, not categories. Again, I'm not sure why you want to do what you described, but have a look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-bulk-attribute-manager/ - maybe it'll help.

Comment: The client does not want to see extra attributes in the Dropdown attribute that can not relate to a specific category.
For example, if the user has selected the category of "doors" it should not see the attribute of "depth" and "thickness"

Comment: Have a look: http://epo.themecomplete.com/documentation/woocommerce-tm-extra-product-options/index.html#global